# RabbitMq FreeBsd - Shared object "libdl.so.1" not found, required by "beam.smp"

Tags: rabbitmq, freebsd

I just install rabbitmq-3.7.8 on my FreeBsd mashine.
But if I run  **rabbitmqctl start**, then getting error is

*Shared object "libdl.so.1" not found, required by "beam.smp"*

**uname -v**

FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p4 #0: Tue Nov 14 06:12:40 UTC 2017

What is that mean?
Thanks for any answer!

Comment: How did you install it? ports/packages etc.?

Comment: No. As pkg install rabbitmq-3.7.8

Comment: It looks like you run it as a service. Try `service rabbitmqctl start`.

Answer (score 5):

You are using 11.1 which is discontinued. I strongly recommended that you upgrade to 11.2.

```
freebsd-update upgrade -r 11.2-RELEASE
freebsd-update install
reboot
freebsd-update install
```

Check again your OS version.

```
uname -r
```

It should return 11.2-RELEASE

```
pkg update -f
pkg upgrade -f
```

All your packages will be reinstalled, then check again if rabbitmqctl starts.

Comment: Version 11.1 was not "discontinued". I'm not sure about the support for it, as I always keep our machines up-to-date, but this will not cause software to not work any more.

Comment: Proper `pkg` syntax is `pkg update -f` and `pkg upgrade -f`.

Answer (score 1):

11.1 went [End-of-Life](https://www.freebsd.org/security/unsupported.html) slightly less than two months before your post.

If you're not ready to upgrade yet, but have access to a machine running 11.2, you can probably copy `/usr/lib/libdl.so.1` from the newer machine into `/usr/lib` on the older machine, and limp along like that until you're ready to upgrade.